# add sub_menu to a sub_menu (multiLevel sub_menu) in admin menu in wordpress

Tags: admin-menu, sub-menu, add-menu-page

I'm looking to add a submenu, to another sub_menu that already exists.
In WordPress, there are just 2 levels of admin menu (with functions: `add_menu_page` and `add_submenu_page`), my goal is to add another sub_memu, to be in level 3, to the one in level 2, how can I do that?

Comment: you can't have a 3rd layer of menus, such a layer does not exist in the admin menu

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to have a 3rd layer menu. Look at the definition of `[add_submenu_page]` .   https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/ .It states that you need to include the parent slug. You can attempt to do it with some front end work around.